# How to count the number of unique values in a group of rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a file with about 5000 rows like the following
[excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke2NT.png)

I need to write Y in column "Mixed country" IF there are more than one country for the given group.
If there is only one destination country for a given group number, write N in "Mixed country"

[image]

What would be a fitting formula for this ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With latest version of Office 365 there are new, very powerful functions, with them you can write this formula:

`=IF(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8=A2)))>1,"Y","N")`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data starts in column A you can use the below in C2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)<>COUNTIF(B:B,B2),"Y","N")
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It may be saver to use `COUNTIFS()` in case a country can fall in a multiple groups (who knows) >> `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2),"Y","N")`

Comment: Indeed, a country can be seen in multiple groups.
Your solution and Máté Juhász's work. Thank you!